# Proof of funds for a US Visitor Visa Application

Tags: visas, usa, bangladeshi-citizens, proof-of-funds

I am applying for visitor visa in US, while staying in Canada. I do work remotely (outsourcing/freelancing) for a company in US to make my living in Canada (I do have contracts). Though my money comes through third party outsourcing sites (odesk.com)

I am just wondering, I can (and should I at all?) mention about the fact that I am a freelancer in my US visitor visa application?

If yes, what kind of document I should take in time of interview? Will the contract with my company work or is anything more needed?

If no, what should I tell about source of my living costs here?

Comment: Are you applying for a business or leisure visitor visa? If your job is being a freelancer and you earn your living this way and should prove you can pay your living costs, why not saying it? Is your worry that the company making you live is based in the US?

Comment: What is your country of Passport? This may actually be quite an interesting question, in that the US DoS may be hesitant to issue a visa in that the OP is already working for US companies. If the OP has not familial ties to return to in Canada (an assumption) where is the impetus to leave the US?

Comment: @Vince right, that is what I am worrying about.

Comment: @CGCampbell, My country of Passport is 'Bangladesh'. I am staying in Canada as a masters student. Yes, I am also thinking what to tell about the ties? For I only have saying only about returning my home country and complete my study in Canada. Do you have any suggestion?